# How to use jquery for getting style of div

Tags: jquery

I want to make a function to change the `display` style from `none` to `block`. I have tried using jQuery's `each()`, but I don't know where I went wrong or how to correct it.

I have used the for each jQuery using an array but I got an error when I tried to use this.

```js
var ar = [];
ar.push(x1a, x2a, x3a, x4a, x5a, x6a);

$.each(ar, function() {
  console.log(ar[5]);
  if (ar.style.display === "none") {
    ar.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x1">hello 1</p>
  <span id="x1a" style="display: none;">hello 1 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x2">hello 2</p>
  <span id="x2a" style="display: none;">hello 2 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x3">hello 3</p>
  <span id="x3a" style="display: none;">hello 3 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x4">hello 4</p>
  <span id="x4a" style="display: none;">hello 4 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x5">hello 5</p>
  <span id="x5a" style="display: none;">hello 5 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x6">hello 6</p>
  <span id="x6a" style="display: none;">hello 6 hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `ar` is the whole array. The current element of the iteration is `this`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ar = [];
    ar.push(x1a,x2a,x3a,x4a,x5a,x6a);
    //console.log(ar[0]);
    //var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$.each(ar , function() { 
  console.log(ar[5]);
  if (this.style.display === "none") {
    this.style.display = "block";}
});
```

The following code worked for me
Thanks to @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that `ar` is a reference to the entire array. You need to access each individual element within it instead. To do that, `$.each()` provides two arguments to the function handler, the second of which is the current element in the iterator. As such your code should look like the following example:

```js
var ar = [];
ar.push(x1a, x2a, x3a, x4a, x5a, x6a);

$.each(ar, function(i, el) {
  if (el.style.display === "none") {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x1">hello 1</p>
  <span id="x1a" style="display: none;">hello 1 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x2">hello 2</p>
  <span id="x2a" style="display: none;">hello 2 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x3">hello 3</p>
  <span id="x3a" style="display: none;">hello 3 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x4">hello 4</p>
  <span id="x4a" style="display: none;">hello 4 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x5">hello 5</p>
  <span id="x5a" style="display: none;">hello 5 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x6">hello 6</p>
  <span id="x6a" style="display: none;">hello 6 hello</span>
</div>
```

***However*** you should note that your code is much more complicated than it needs to be.

If your goal is to simply toggle the display state of the `span` within `.div` elements, select them and call `toggle()`, like this:

```js
$('.div span').toggle();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x1">hello 1</p>
  <span id="x1a" style="display: none;">hello 1 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x2">hello 2</p>
  <span id="x2a" style="display: none;">hello 2 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x3">hello 3</p>
  <span id="x3a" style="display: none;">hello 3 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x4">hello 4</p>
  <span id="x4a" style="display: none;">hello 4 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x5">hello 5</p>
  <span id="x5a" style="display: none;">hello 5 hello</span>
</div>
<div class="div">
  <p id="x6">hello 6</p>
  <span id="x6a" style="display: none;">hello 6 hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: no cannot use that as i have other event function for span where it can be toggled i have to do it by calling through id

Comment: That doesn't make sense given the example in the question as the jQuery I provided performs the exact same function as the original code. In either case I have expanded the answer to correct your original code, and explain why it was not working.

Comment: yes I was not clear with what i need in question but i wanted to use if statement